# Zufällig vs. zufälligerweise vs. per Zufall

Tags: difference

I know three different ways of saying "coincidentally":

- zufällig
- zufälligerweise
- per Zufall

But somehow I get the feeling, due to the reactions I get, that they are not always interchangeable, at least not in all situations.

Could someone give me a more detailed insight on in which situations one works better than the other, or in which situations they don't work at all?

Comment: The first one should be "zufällig"... "zufälliger" is an adjective meaning "random" or "coincidental"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. „zufällig“ is an adjective/adverb, as in:

> Ich habe ihn *zufällig* getroffen. („I met him coincidentally“, used as adverb)
>   Die Verteilung der Ergebnisse ist *zufällig* („The distribution of the results is random“, used as adjective)

„zufälligerweise“ is an adverb:

> Ich habe ihn *zufälligerweise* getroffen.
>   *Die Verteilung der Ergebnisse ist *zufälligerweise*

„per Zufall“ oder „durch Zufall“ can be translated as „by chance„, it can denote that something happens by chance or is done by using coincidence:

> Ich habe ihn *durch Zufall* getroffen(I met him by chance)
>   Die Verteilung der Ergebnisse ist *durch Zufall* (bestimmt)
>   Ich habe ihn per Zufall getroffen
>   #Die Verteilung der Ergebnisse wird *per Zufall* bestimmt.

The second works with „bestimmt“ but might be understandable, yet awkward without. The fourth means that coincidence is the method to get results (like: „Die Lottozahlen werden durch Zufall bestimmt/ermittelt“).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say that something happened coincidentally (by chance), you could use

- zufällig
- zufälligerweise
- per Zufall

They are all adverbs (or adverb phrases), as they refer to a verb. Their meaning is roughly the same. Most of the time *zufällig* would be totally sufficient.

Example: *Wir trafen uns zufällig.* (*We met coincidentally*.)

*zufälliger* is an adjective. It refers to a noun.  inflected for masculine gender in the nominal case. The translation would be *coincidental*, not *coincidentally*. Example: *Ein zufälliger Wert.* (*A coincidental value.*)